# Is it possible to get an array of unique values in firebase?

Tags: angularjs, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, angularfire

Consider the following data stored in Firebase:

```js
{
  "beers": {
    "-jwhkclclmecl": {
      "name": "Two Hearted Ale",
      "type": "IPA",
      "brewery": "Bells"
    },
    "-ckqjheh292od": {
      "name": "Dirty Blonde Ale",
      "type": "Pale Wheat",
      "brewery": "Atwater"
    },
    "-hcwiu3cp902d": {
      "name": "Diabolical",
      "type": "IPA",
      "brewery": "North Peak"
    }
  }
}
```

Is it possible to build a query for Firebase to return an array of the unique values of one of the child nodes. For example to return `["IPA", "Pale Wheat"]`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Nope, you cannot query a collection for unique values of a specific property of each item. You can filter on such values, so `ref.child('beers').orderByChild('type').equalTo('IPA')`. But that's not what you were asking. :-)

Typically if you want this type of operation in Firebase (or most other NoSQL databases), you'll keep the items (or references to the items) under a group:

```
{
  "beer_types": {
    "IPA": {
      "-jwhkclclmecl": {
        "name": "Two Hearted Ale",
        "brewery": "Bells"
      },
      "-hcwiu3cp902d": {
        "name": "Diabolical",
        "brewery": "North Peak"
      }
    },
    "Pale Wheat": {
      "-ckqjheh292od": {
        "name": "Dirty Blonde Ale",
        "brewery": "Atwater"
      },
    }
  }
}
```

Of course that only works if you want to only keep them in one category. If you want multiple categories, you can store references to each item under multiple categories:

```
{
  "beers": {
    "-jwhkclclmecl": {
      "name": "Two Hearted Ale",
      "type": "IPA",
      "brewery": "Bells"
    },
    "-ckqjheh292od": {
      "name": "Dirty Blonde Ale",
      "type": "Pale Wheat",
      "brewery": "Atwater"
    },
    "-hcwiu3cp902d": {
      "name": "Diabolical",
      "type": "IPA",
      "brewery": "North Peak"
    }
  }
  "beer_types": {
    "IPA": {
      "-jwhkclclmecl": true,
      "-hcwiu3cp902d": true
    },
    "Pale Wheat": {
      "-ckqjheh292od": true
    }
  },
  "breweries": {
    "Bells": {
      "-jwhkclclmecl": true
    },
    "Atwater": {
      "-ckqjheh292od": true
    }
    "North Peak": {
      "-hcwiu3cp902d": true
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Cool thanks. This is [mostly] what I was doing, but I wanted to be sure that firebase didn't provide an easier way. Thanks!

Comment: Is it still the case in 2020? or is there any way because I kind of desperately need that feature since i upload data to firebase.

Comment: Yes, this is still the same. If you want something to be unique, store those things as the **key** under a node and use transactions to mutate that node. A search for [unique values on Firebase](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bfirebase-realtime-database%5D+unique+value) will give you many more questions (and answers) on the topic.

Answer (score 1):

As Frank said, no.  Denormalize the grouping you are wanting to SELECT DISTINCT.  In my case, I want to populate drop down lists (HTML Select Group) for city and state, which are key/value pairs for each of my meetings.  So, I will have state drop down fill with results of my "states" firebase node.  Once state is selected, I will populate the city dropdown with the list of that states cities.

As for how to create this group in Firebase, below is what I came up with.  Simply change "city" and "state" with "item" and "group" to fit your needs.  No need to check for duplicates upon writing as they are not written by default.  This function will create your group (NOTE: Have your strings .toLowerCase() prior to calling this with them)

```
function setCity(city,state){
    if (city && state){
        var statesRef = ref.child('states');
        var stateRef = statesRef.child(state);
        var obj = {};
        obj[city] = true;           
        stateRef.update(obj);
    }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score -1):

Firebase has no native support for arrays. If you store an array, it really gets stored as an “object” with integers as the key names.

```
// we send this
['IPA', 'Pale Wheat']
// Firebase stores this
{0: 'IPA', 1: 'Pale Wheat'}
```